# Need to open wechat mini program from chat location

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

We want to forward WeChat message as Mail using our applet. How to configure to open WeChat mini program from SMS/chat location?

Answer (score 0):

At first, open wechat-miniprogram from other apps means that the app open the wechat and transform params to open miniprogram.
It needs to download android and ios wechat-sdk package into your apps.
Using the method of wechat-sdk package to auth and open wechat in your sence.
To hope it could help you.
Docs:https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/oplatform/en/Mobile_App/Launching_a_Mini_Program/Launching_a_Mini_Program.html

Comment: Thanks for replying! We want to open a mini-program from WeChat message location. When a user clicks on a message in Wechat, we want to use our mini programme to forward it as an email.

Comment: Maybe, i didn't understand your words before.It's the methods about opening wechat-mini-program from other apps.But, you may want to send mail while user click the wechat message.If it's yes, the direction of something to do is how to open your mini-program on wechat message.Shared mini-program Card can open it.And the mini-program link can open it.The mini-program link is created by user  by way of clicking the top-right (it has three dots) and opening a menu.And then you will see it.The wechat need to update to the lastest version .